# Getting a "is not a function" error while running a test (javascript, cypress)

Tags: javascript, cypress

below is my code and when I run my test it comes up as months is not a function.  This is for a cypress test.  Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
class DateUtils {
  getMonthIndexFromName(monthName) {
    months = {
      January: '1',
      Febuary: '2',
      March: '3',
      April: '4',
      May: '5',
      June: '6',
      July: '7',
      August: '8',
      September: '9',
      October: '10',
      Novemebr: '11',
      December: '12',
    };
    return months(monthName);
  }
}
export default DateUtils;
```

Comment: It should be `return months[monthName]`
You are accessing the object as if it was a method.

Comment: if you are trying to access the months object use square brackets `return months[monthName]`

Answer (score 1):

`months` is an object, not a function. What you probably want is `months[monthName]` to dynamically select the property in `monthName` from the `months` object.